# Different colours per menu option (with Fade effect)

Tags: jquery, background, background-color

I would like to change the background colour of page each time you click a particular tab... 
So each time they click a tab... it would fade in the new set colour for that tab.

The tab script I use already uses jQuery.

Something so simple prob but ive been having problems with this for wayy too long, hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/6gWkM/)

```
$("#mytab1").click(function(e) {
    $("body").css({ background: "#123456" });
});

$("#mytab2").click(function(e) {
    $("body").css({ background: "#456789" });
});
```

If you need to interpolate the color, you'll need to include jQuery UI as well. [Here is a fade demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/6gWkM/1/)

```
$("#mytab1").click(function(e) {
    $("body").animate({backgroundColor: '#123456'}, 'slow');
});

$("#mytab2").click(function(e) {
    $("body").animate({backgroundColor: '#abc456'}, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! How can add the fade in effect for each of the colours?